# php - simpleXML help

Tags: php, simplexml

I have this XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Days>
  <day value="1">
    <Imsaak>04:59</Imsaak>
    <Fajr>05:09</Fajr>
    <Sunrise>06:23</Sunrise>
    <Dhuhr>12:39</Dhuhr>
    <Asr>16:12</Asr>
    <Sunset>18:55</Sunset>
    <Maghrib>19:10</Maghrib>
    <Isha>20:04</Isha>
  </day>
  <day value="2">
    <Imsaak>04:58</Imsaak>
    <Fajr>05:08</Fajr>
    <Sunrise>06:22</Sunrise>
    <Dhuhr>12:39</Dhuhr>
    <Asr>16:12</Asr>
    <Sunset>18:56</Sunset>
    <Maghrib>19:11</Maghrib>
    <Isha>20:05</Isha>
  </day>
</Days>
```

and I want to select `<day>` node depending on the attribute value

I am using SimpleXMLElement class but I don't how to select with arrtibute value.

how I can do that??

EDIT: my code :

```
include 'days.xml';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

foreach ($xml->day as $day) {
   // process data
}
```

Comment: please show what you have written till now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from php manual [SimpleXMLElement::attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) (little bit edited)

Considering this data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
   <item ID="30001">
      <Company>Navarro Corp.</Company>
   </item>
   <item ID="30002">
      <Company>Performant Systems</Company>
   </item>
   <item ID="30003">
      <Company>Digital Showcase</Company>
   </item>
</data>
```

Example of listing both the ID Attribute and Company Element values:

```
<?php
$xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);
foreach ($xmlObject->children() as $node) {
        $arr = $node->attributes();   // returns an array
        if(in_array("30002", $arr)){     // search the value of an attribute
            print ("Company=".$node->Company);
        }
        //depending of your needs, you could use a switch / case instead of use an if

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr)
$xml->day[0]->attribute()->value;//will echo out 1
```

of course you can loop through all of the day like this:

```
foreach($sml->day as $day){
     $day->attribute()->value; //will trace out 1 and then 2
}
```